# React state passed as prop does not update in child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I wonder if someone could explain why when the returned zones of each function, are passed down to a child as props, the first function updates the props and renders the child, but a small change in the second function targets the exact values required does not? I think I may be losing the original reference somehow, but do not know how to fix it. Thanks in advance

```
getAudioControls1(controls,rooms){    
    let zones = []
    
    for (const key in controls) {
        if (controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const element = controls[key];
            if (element.type === "InfoOnlyText" && element.name === "Synched") {   
                let room = this.getReqRoom(element.room, rooms)
                element.roomName = room.name
                zones.push(element)
            }
        }
    }    
    return zones
}
```

```
getAudioControls2(controls,rooms){
    let zones = []
    for (const key in controls) {
        if (controls.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const element = controls[key]; 
            if (element.type === "InfoOnlyText" && element.name === "Synched") {     
                let room = this.getReqRoom(element.room, rooms)
                let rawZones = []
                element.roomName = room.name
                rawZones.push(element.roomName,element.statesValue.text)
                zones.push(rawZones)
            }
        }    
    }
    return zones
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you push `element` (I guess it's an object) to `zones`. As a result you have array of objects.

In the second you push array `rawZones` to your `zones`. As a result you have array of arrays.

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed returning an array of arrays in the second function, but the property i want to be updated is still referenced by the original reference i.e element.stateValue.text, which is placed in an array This has got me thinking that I destroying the original reference to this.state.controls. This original has many properties that are not needed. obj.a , obj.b obj.c etc. How can i remove these properties but keep the same original reference.